# Configure SQL Server access

Tags: sql-server-2008, connection-string

How to configure SQL Server to access only by dot symbol as server name

```
<add connectionString="Server=.;Database=aspnetdb;User ID=ccadbuser;Password=123456" name="LocalSqlServer" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean - that you want to accept connections **ONLY** from local machine - then disable network protocols tcp and netpipe in sql server configuration utility. Leave only shared memory

If you insist on dot - make it programmatically, like this in c#

```
var csb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(YourConnString);
csb.DataSource = ".";

var c = new SqlConnection(csb.ToString());

do all you need
```

Comment: I would like to use dot symbol in webconfig.file. I've made changes that you described. But I cannot to connect to the sql server instance with dot symbol